# MYSQL insert random from list

Tags: mysql, random

I would like to add a random value to a table. While I know how to add random integers within a range, I am currently stumped on how to add a randomly selected item from a list.

Let's say I have a MYSQL table for IM accounts. I would like to fill it with random data.

```
INSERT INTO `im` (`im`, `service`)
SELECT LOWER(`last`), RANDOM-SELECTION-HERE
FROM `contact`;
```

What this query should do is add to the IM table the contact's last name with a random selection from an array I would give. For example, the array would be:

```
['AIM', 'ICQ', 'MSN', 'Yahoo', 'GTalk', 'Other']
```

So, I would like to add the users last name plus one of the random items from the array.

**NOTE: *I know this is fully possible with a programming language such as PHP, Perl, etc., but I am not trying to do that. Please try to provide a way to do this strictly with MYSQL.***

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `im`
(`im`, `service`)
SELECT LOWER(`last`),
    ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 6, 'AIM', 'ICQ', 'MSN', 'Yahoo', 'GTalk', 'Other')
FROM `contact`
```

Comment: Worked beautifully and easily to understand. Thank you :)

Comment: Note that `0.5 + RAND() * 6` will return values between 0 and 6 inclusive, with 0 returning a NULL value from ELT().

`1 + RAND() * 6` will return values between 1 and 6 inclusive which will mean ELT() always returns a result from the list.

Comment: @AndyBurton: Incorrect.  The first argument to `ELT()`, if floating-point, is rounded to produce an index; 0.5 plus any number >= 0 cannot round to 0.

Comment: @AndyBurton: Also, `1 + RAND() * 6` produces values from 1 to 7 inclusive, thereby exceeding the list size and producing `NULL`s.

Comment: @chaos my apologies i'd wrapped it in FLOOR whilst flicking back to the MySQL docs, which was producing 0-6 inclusive, i changed it to `FLOOR(1+RAND()*6)` to get 1-6 inclusive. The mysql line was `To obtain a random integer R in the range i <= R < j, use the expression FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i)).`

Comment: Note: This even works during an update

Answer (score 12):

If you're willing to add the services to another table...

```
INSERT INTO `im` ( `im` , `service` )
SELECT LOWER( `last` ) , (
   SELECT `service`
   FROM `service`
   ORDER BY RAND( )
   LIMIT 1
)
FROM `contact`
```

Comment: that was awesome, exactly what i was looking for