# How to insert random numbers MySql

Tags: mysql

Im new to MySql, and I need to insert into table 10000 random 2-digit numbers. Is there Easy way to to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL insert random from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301935/mysql-insert-random-from-list)

Comment: Write a stored procedure with a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE random_fill( IN cnt INT )
BEGIN

    fold: LOOP

         IF cnt < 1 THEN
             LEAVE fold;
         END IF;

        INSERT INTO foo ( bar ) VALUES ( 9 + CEIL( RAND() * 90 ) );

        SET cnt = cnt - 1;
    END LOOP fold;

END$$   
DELIMIMTER ;
```

To use this:

```
CALL random_fill(10000);
```

What you have to change is this line:

```
INSERT INTO foo ( bar ) VALUES ( CEIL( RAND() * higher ) );
```

Replace the `foo` and `bar` with something that exists in your database. It **is** possible to create a procedure, where the name of table and row are also supplied as parameters, but that would require to `CONCAT` the query on fly .. looks hack'ish and ugly.

Comment: I would recommend putting a transaction in there. Without it, 100K inserts timed out 22k, with it, 100K took 4.047 seconds on my dev machine.

Answer (score 18):

Use `RAND()` as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). For generating 2-digit random numbers between 10 and 99, use `FLOOR(10 + (RAND() * 90))`.

Comment: I used your formula in my answer. +1 for you so I can avoid copyright infringement !!!