# Updating table, choosing between 3 random strings - how?

Tags: mysql

I'm making standard profile pictures for 5000 users, and right now i need to insert a referance in the 'users' table. I don't want all the users to have the same standard profile picture, so i'm trying to update the 'user_profile_image' row with one of the strings listen in the query below.

```
UPDATE users 
SET user_profile_image = rand('adrian.jpg', 'bendix.jpg', 
hr_skaeg.jpg', `'jeppe.jpg')
```

The query doesn't seem to work.

Is this way too simple?

Any help is much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Mathias

Comment: see this seems good [random insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301935/mysql-insert-random-from-list)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`RAND()` returns a number between 0 and 1; if you multiply it by the number of pictures you have and take the `FLOOR()`, you can switch on the result with `ELT`:

```
UPDATE users SET user_profile_image =
 ELT(1 + FLOOR(RAND()*4), 'adrian.jpg', 'bendix.jpg', 'hr_skaeg.jpg', 'jeppe.jpg');
```

Comment: Just beat me to the example :)

Comment: @Cylindric: No worries - you have my +1 anyway :)

Comment: It said that I had to wait 5 minutes last i checked, will accept the answers :)

Comment: @eggyal: what's `0.5` offset here for?

Comment: @zerkms:  Weird.  I don't recall.  Looks like it should be 1, to give a parameter to `ELT()` between 1 and 4... perhaps in my head I was using a rounding function instead of `FLOOR()`?

Comment: @eggyal: yep, `ROUND()` would explain it

Comment: I submitted an edit with the code fixed (0.5 changed to 1), but it was rejected as incorrect. I'm submitting it again, because I can't find anything wrong with it. If rejecting, please add a comment to explain why.

Comment: Oh well, my second edit was rejected again. @eggyal would you mind updating the answer yourself, or approving my edit if that's possible? Thanks.

Comment: @JonColverson: Not sure why your edits were rejected; both times I got round to them only after they had already been declined - else I would have approved them!  Anyway, I rolled back my previous edit to use an offset of 1 again; not really sure why I changed it to 0.5 in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

You need to read the manual. [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE users
SET user_profile_image = 
    CASE FLOOR(RAND() * 4) 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'adrian.jpg.img' 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'bendix.jpg' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'hr_skaeg.jpg' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'jeppe.jpg' 
    END
```

;