# Picking a random number from a group of numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, random

Is there a way to insert a random number selected from a group of numbers, ie I want to randomly insert a 2, 3, 5, 6, or 7 into a field. It has to be one of those numbers and can't be a different one. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry I found what I was looking for...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301935/mysql-insert-random-from-list?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

so you would need something like

```
SELECT mid('23567',FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 5)),1);
```