# Add random numbers in database

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have an array of 5 numbers. I am using event scheduling to insert rows after every 5 seconds, but it keeps on inserting the first value only.
how can I insert different values of array at every insert in mysql.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  require_once('con.php');  
  $numb = array(101,245,342,894,45);
  $random = array_rand($numb);
  for($a=0;$a<=5;$a++)
  {
        $query = "CREATE EVENT myEvent1 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND DO BEGIN INSERT INTO emp(emp_id) VAlUES('$numb[$random]'); END";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Because you've selected 1 random number and then told MySQL to insert it every 5 seconds or whatever that is doing.

Comment: Try moving `$random = array_rand($numb);` inside the loop before the `$query = ` so that you get a new random number each time through the loop for an insert.

Comment: what do you mean? you mean every 5 seconds you insert A RANDOM ROW(1 number) in the database?

Comment: yess..I want to insert a new random row every 5 seconds with a different number everytime

Comment: you mean the next insert should not be the same as the previous one?

Comment: Yess. It should not be the same as the previous one but any number from the array

Comment: that's it. your question is misleading them guys. im sure you'll get an answer now

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the random number in `PHP` and passing it to `MySQL`, which is being used every 5 seconds. Instead you need to do the random part in `MySQL` so that you get random every time. (Referred to this : [MYSQL insert random from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301935/mysql-insert-random-from-list) )

```
$query = "CREATE EVENT myEvent1 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND DO BEGIN INSERT INTO emp(emp_id) VAlUES(ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 5, 101, 245, 342, 894, 45)); END";
```

Comment: its not working.This code stoppped the insertion part too :(

Comment: heyy it worked..I dont know how but it did. Thankyou soo so much :)

Comment: actually i had missed one bracket ')'

Comment: Whoever downvoted, any explanation will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
  $numb = array('101','245','342','894','45');
```

Or This:

```
array_rand(array_flip($numb), $n);
```

Look at this For More Info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php